# Make Multiple background work on IE

Tags: html, css

I want to use multiple background from CSS3 on IE8 and earlier browsers. I downloaded modenizer library and detect whether browser supports multiple background or not through this code:

```
if(Modernizr.multiplebgs){
    alert("Your browser supports multiplebgs, enjoy!!");
} else {
    alert("Sorry, browser does not support multiplebgs tag!");
}
```

What should I do in the else section to make multiple background work on IE8 and earlier versions?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple backgrounds will only work if you are using IE 9.0+, IE8 and earlier do not implement this feature.  I don't know if there's alternative method of doing something similar for IE8 and lower, but for this particular feature, there's nothing you can do to make it work in IE8 and below.

Edit:
I looked around a bit, and it seems like there's some slight workarounds for css3 features that aren't supported in older IE browsers.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

There's a multiple backgrounds alternative listed on this site, but ultimately, it won't be as flexible and useful as the css3 one.  I'm not sure if the situation in which you can use this workaround will apply to you, but you can take a look for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I bet you could use javascript to choose a random url for an img and insert it as a background div for a full screen background. That could work for most browsers.

For the css full image :

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Then you could have multiple images on the server such as : bg1.png, bg2.png, ...

Javascript `var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)`

Then use a variable in javascript for the number after the img and insert it in your background-image :

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = background-image:url('bg'+randomnumber);

Of course you will have some edits to do with my code here.
I just hope you get the idea :)